# How can I disable zoom in the status bar of Internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, zoom, statusbar

I want to disable zoom available in the status bar of IE.
How can I do this? Is it possible using JavaScript?

Comment: I hope not (the browser is running on *my* computer using *my* resources). If you explain why you need this there may be another solution.

Comment: @Richard i assume he means on his own computer (This is superuser, after all). A good reason to revert to the old zoom behavior (zooming changes text size only), is that IE is very slow at rendering resized content. Flash and animated gifs are especially bad. (Though this will be fixed in ie9 with it's hardware rendering)

Comment: @Richard  0
 
I have to do this in a web application so that user can't zoom.

Comment: @Vis - this is not possible. You are sending web pages, which is basically code. This code is interpreted by the browser, on the user's side, to render it as a full page. You can't control the fact that the browser can render it bigger or smaller than what you want, from the website side. This zoom is only a client thing, there is no way to block it from your side.

Comment: @Vishawjeet: You need to ask development (including creating the web pages) questions on StackOverflow. SuperUser is end user Q&A.

Comment: @Richard: Ok I will ask in stackoverflow... Thanks for information

Answer (score 3):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933053), you can disable the zoom feature by adding registry values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft`.

1. Add key **Internet Explorer** with subkey **Zoom**.
2. Add a `DWORD` (32-bit) to the subkey called **ZoomDisabled** and a value of **1**.

Comment: FYI: This solution only works for the end-client, not for arbitrary web pages (which, to my knowledge, cannot disable zooming).

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally there's no reason to fight a user's DPI settings. If i set Windows to 200dpi and run at a high resolution, then the browser will work.

Your web-site will also work, you don't have to change anything.

The only thing you might want to deal with is the fact that my higher resolution monitor can display higher resolution images, but you continue to feed me those low resolution 540x120 logos.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> [Making the Web Bigger: DPI Scaling and Internet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> There are times when you might want to know at which DPI Scaling a user is viewing your Web page. You can find this information by querying the screen.deviceXDPI or screen.deviceYDPI DOM property. For example, if the page is zoomed to 125%, screen.deviceXDPI will return 120 (120/96 equals 1.25, or 125%). Note, however, that the value returned is entirely dependent on the zoom state of Internet Explorer and not necessarily the DPI Scaling Setting of Windows. For example, if your Windows DPI Scaling is set to 144 DPI and you are viewing a Web page at 100% zoom, screen.deviceXDPI will return 96 (96/96 equals 1, or 100%), not 144.
>
> Once you have the DPI information, you can:
>
> - Make layout tweaks to optimize for different DPIs.
> - Swap in higher-resolution images to take advantage of the extra pixels available to you (thus avoiding the use of imperfect image interpolation).
> - Place elements on a Web page relative to the browser chrome.

It's like asking users not to browse your web-site on a *Retina Display* iPhone because its resolution is too high.